# Arduino Two Port Receive not working?

Tags: arduino

I am currently planning to use SoftwareSerial for 2 pairs of (tx,rx) on Arduino Uno.

I have the following code:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

#define EC_RX 8     // Make sure RX<->TX!!!!
#define EC_TX 9
#define PH_RX 10
#define PH_TX 11

SoftwareSerial ecSerial(EC_RX, EC_TX);
SoftwareSerial phSerial(PH_RX, PH_TX);

String ecSensorString = "";
bool ecSensorComplete = false;
String phSensorString = "";
bool phSensorComplete = false;


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(38400);
  ecSerial.begin(38400);
  phSerial.begin(38400);

  ecSensorString.reserve(30);
  phSensorString.reserve(30);

  delay(5000);
  Serial.println("Setup Complete");
}

void getEC() {
  Serial.println("getEC");
  ecSerial.listen();
  while (ecSerial.available()) {
    char inchar = (char)ecSerial.read();
    ecSensorString += inchar;
    if (inchar == '\r') {
      ecSensorComplete = true;
    }
  }

  if (ecSensorComplete) {
    Serial.println(ecSensorString);
    ecSensorString = "";
    ecSensorComplete = false;
  }
}

void getPH() {
  Serial.println("getPH");
  phSerial.listen();
  while (phSerial.available()) {
    char inchar = (char)phSerial.read();
    phSensorString += inchar;
    if (inchar == '\r') {
      phSensorComplete = true;
    }
  }

  if (phSensorComplete) {
    Serial.println(phSensorString);
    phSensorString = "";
    phSensorComplete = false;
  }
}


void loop() {
  getEC();
  getPH();
  delay(5000);
}
```

If I comment out `getEC()` inside `loop()`, I get the following readings:

```
Setup Complete
getPH
3.22
```

If I comment out `getPH()` inside `loop()`, I get:

```
Setup Complete
getEC
0.00,0,0.00,1.000
```

However, if I leave both of these *uncommented*, I am getting:

```
Setup Complete
getEC
getPH
```

It seems like even with `Serial.listen()`, my serial ports are not functioning as expected. My pins are following the wiring found out http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/TwoPortReceive.

What gives?

Comment: Softserial might be deprecated now, as there's a newsoftwareserial. Do note the limitations: http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/SoftwareSerial, you can only listen on one software serial port at a time. And there's some nasty stuff going on with interrupts internally. The workaround seems to be ugly